# Angular: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'li'

Tags: angular

Hi I am getting this error in Visual Code and angular 10:

**Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'li'**

in parts I will attach  all of my code int his component, I don't know to resolve it.

My html template is:

[image]

my component ts is:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import {
  CommunicationService
} from '../../share/communication/communication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menumovil',
  templateUrl: './menu-movil.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-movil.component.scss']
})
export class MenuMovilComponent implements OnInit {
  public esNosaltres = false;
  public esInicio = true;
  public esCarne = false;
  public esVerdura = false;
  public esFruta = false;
  public esProducto = false;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private communication: CommunicationService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  public allMenuoff = () => {
    this.esNosaltres = false;
    this.esInicio = false;
    this.esCarne = false;
    this.esFruta = false;
    this.esVerdura = false;
    this.esProducto = false;
  }

  public eventOnClickMenu = (tipo: string) => {
    this.communication.setMenuType(tipo);

    this.allMenuoff();

    switch (tipo) {
      case 'inicio':
        this.esInicio = true;
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        break;
      case 'nosaltres':
        this.esNosaltres = true;
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/nosotros');
        break;
      case 'producto':
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        this.esProducto = true;
        break;
      case 'fruta':
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        this.esFruta = true;
        break;
      case 'verdura':
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        this.esVerdura = true;
        break;
      case 'carne':
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        this.esCarne = true;
        break;
    }

  }
}
```

the module is:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule
} from '@angular/forms';

import { MenuMovilComponent } from './menu-movil.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MenuMovilComponent],
  exports: [MenuMovilComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

    NgModule
    ]
})
export class MenuMovilModule { }
```

in styles.scss I have:

```
.activoOn {
  background-color: black !important;

}

.activoOn a {
  color: silver !important;
}

.activoOff {
  background-color: unset !important;
}
```

If you need more information let me know

Why am I getting this error?

Thx

========================================================================
UPDATE 1:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MenuComponent],
  exports: [ MenuComponent ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule, // <<------ not working with it...
    NgModule
  ]
})
```

========================================================================
UPDATE 2:

In terminal I have this:

[image]

And in console:
[image]

My app-routing is:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  RouterModule,
  Routes
} from '@angular/router';

import { MenuMovilComponent } from './menumovil/menu-movil.component';
import { NosotrosComponent } from './nosotros/nosotros.component';
import {
  ViewsCarouselComponent
} from './views-carousel/views-carousel.component';

const routes: Routes = [


      { path: 'views', component: ViewsCarouselComponent },
      { path: 'nosotros', component: NosotrosComponent },
      { path: 'menu', component: MenuMovilComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'views', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },

];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am importing it in app.module.

Comment: BrowserModule should be only imported in the root module. Your code seems right to me. I'm guessing you get that error, either because you haven't imported your module in another module that is consumed by the app or your IDE needs a restart. If the issue persists create a stackblitz and I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: I agree with @ionut-t, restart sometimes resolves these strange issues.

Comment: I was restarting it and I didn't get the solution yet. I think the code is ok. I updated with new information the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the CommonModule/BrowserModule/FormsModule/NgModule and it's still not working then make sure you restart and then build your angular application. If it's still not working then you can recheck declarations[] and import[] arrays in app.module.ts file.

Comment: As an Angular novice, I'm not sure what I should be checking for in the declarations and imports.

Answer (score 3):

Import `BrowserModule` in your NgModule:

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, ...]
...
})
```